# How to use Field value present in an application and set it into a field present in subform using custom objects. in RSA Archer?

Tags: archer, rsa-archer-grc

How to use Field value present in an application and set it into a field present in subform using custom objects in RSA Archer? Since cross reference relationship is not possible from application to subform.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, but you will have to use two custom objects.
I've done this in Archer v5 in the following way:

Step 1. First custom object should be located in the application itself. This CO will capture the value of the field you want to sent to the Sub-Form. Value of the field should be stored in the web-browser as a cookie value. You can do it using JavaScript as long as cookies are allowed.

Step 2. Second custom object should be located in the sub-form. This CO will read the cookie value passed from the application and populate required fields.

This is how I implemented a similar requirement in the past. Good luck!